# 0 Axes is produced using pcolormesh with matplotlib.pyplot.subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I used to just make one panel in a figure by using plt.pcolormesh(), but I would like to add multiple axes. So, I just give a try to use 1 axes to start with. It is strange it did not work.

My code is:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolormesh(lat_2d[s:e+1,],bin_alt[s:e+1,]/1000,vel_cmb[s:e+1,],shading='gouraud',cmap=cmap,norm=norm)  
plt.show()
```

It generated an error of `Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes`.

However, when I use:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.pcolormesh(lat_2d[s:e+1,],bin_alt[s:e+1,]/1000,vel_cmb[s:e+1,],shading='gouraud',cmap=cmap,norm=norm)  
plt.show()
```

It shows the image I intended to see.

Can anyone help me on explaining or fixing this?

Thank you!

Comment: I tried another way, instead of using plt.subplots, I used plt.add_subplot, and don't use plt.show(), it seems it works now.                                                     fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)  I don't know why it works. Hope it will continue work. Please give me any hint you maybe think of. Thanks.

Comment: Your error is not reproducible. Could you add how you imported `plt`? And also add the full error trace? Which backend are you using?

Comment: I used "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt" to import plt. It is indeed quite strange. Because I remember it worked before. plt.add_subplot() still works now and I added the 2nd axes. I don't know how to do a "full error trace". I also don't understand backend.  Can you please give some references for the concepts at the beginner level? Thanks.

Comment: To understand what's happening, the environment in which you run the code might be important (Jupyter, kivy, interactive window in PyCharm, ...). Also, matplotlib allows to set a ['backend'](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#backends) or use the default backend of your environment.  To better understand the error, it is important that you add a copy of the complete error output, see e.g. [here](https://realpython.com/python-traceback/) for more information. Please don't answer in the comments, but [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64915356/edit) the question.

Comment: I use Jupyter. Thanks for the information. Will try to keep in mind about the environment and backend, error tracking issues along the way. Though I can not figure what was going on, I did made another try of fig.add_subplot() vs plt.subplots(), which is involved with multiple rows and columns of axes. Some of my axes has a color bar. When using fig = plt.figure() and fig.add_subplot(), it works as expected. But when using plt.subplots(), it does not work as expected.